# Declared javascript variable not working in a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

The code is as follows:

```
 var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

 function nameEcho(name) {
     var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + name; // adding the variable to a string
     alert(namephrase); // make a popup with the variable
 }
```

The code above is in a JS file. 
When I trigger the function with a button on a HTML page I get an alert saying: `The saved name is,`

Sorry if this is a super simple question, I am new to JS, but something must be going over my head. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you trigger the function? Share your html also

Comment: How are you **calling** `nameEcho`?

Comment: we need to know how you're calling that function. you should include the rest of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post a question, please *stick around* for a few minutes to answer clarification questions like the above. Stack Overflow is a very active place where people are likely to see your question very quickly and quite possibly have queries like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your function isn't using the variable outside it, because you've shadowed that variable with a function argument:

```
var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

function nameEcho(name) {
// Here ----------^
    var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + name;
    alert(namephrase);
}
```

The `name` argument to the function prevents that function frm being able to use the `name` variable declared outside it.

Options:

1. Pass the name to the function, and probably use a different name for the argument.

   ```
   var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

   function nameEcho(arg) {
       // You can use both `name` and `arg` here
       var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + name; // or `arg`
       alert(namephrase);
   }
   ```
2. Remove the argument if you want to use the variable:

   ```
   var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

   function nameEcho(/*...no `name` here...*/) {
       var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + name;
       alert(namephrase);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `name` as a parameter of the function `nameEcho`, so when you use `name` inside the function it will use the parameter and not the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a local variable named `name` coming as parameter. So it will try to access the value of local variable.

change your code like bellow

```
var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

 function nameEcho(arg) {
        var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + arg; // adding the variable to a string
        alert(namephrase); // make a popup with the variable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments inside the function won't take the variable declared outside function.

The parameters you need to pass as the variable in it's call only.

```
var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

 function nameEcho(n) {
        var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + n; // adding the variable to a string
        alert(namephrase); // make a popup with the variable
    }
```

Now, call like this:

```
nameEcho(name);//which will give you that variable test...
```

---

Or, if you don't care about the parameters and just wanted to use that variable then make function without passing argument like below:

```
var name = 'test'; //declaring variable 

function nameEcho() {
 var namephrase = "The saved name is, " + name; // adding the variable to a string
 alert(namephrase); // make a popup with the variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `name` global variable with the function's parameter.

```
function nameEcho(name) {
     // here 'name' is a different (local) variable than the global
}
```

If your intention is to call the function like this `nameEcho('bob')` you should not declare `name` outside of the function.